# How to parse JSON to List with Maps in Gson?

Tags: json, dictionary, gson

I have the following Java Classes:

```
public class ModuleParsed {

  String id_component;
  String id_instance;
  Map<ModuleParam, ModuleParam> input;
  Map<ModuleParam, List<ModuleParam>> output;
  int id_paas;
}
```

and

```
public class ModuleParam {

  String name;
  Object type;
}
```

what should be the JSON expected to parse it as a `List<ModuleParsed>`?

```
listModules = gson.fromJson(br, new TypeToken<List<ModuleParsed>>() {}.getType());
```

Everything was ok until I introduced the input and output parameters.

**EDIT**

By doing the reverse process I have found the JSON should be something like

```
[
    {
        "id_component": "mod1",
        "id_instance": "mod1_inst1",
        "input": {  
            "moduleParam": {
                "name": "param3",
                "type": "obj3"
            },
            "moduleParam": {
                "name": "param2",
                "type": "obj2"
            }
        },
        "id_paas": 1
    },
    {
        "id_component": "mod2",
        "id_instance": "mod2_inst1",
        "input": {
            "moduleParam": {
                "name": "param3",
                "type": "obj3"
            },
            "moduleParam": {
                "name": "param2",
                "type": "obj2"
            }
        },
        "id_paas": 1
    }
]
```

where the moduleParam elements were something like: `parser.ModuleParam@36c51089`

No matter how I name these elements I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: "moduleParam"
```

How can I obtain the class `ModuleParsed` with Gson?

Comment: Using mutable, complex objects as `Map` keys is a *really bad idea* especially since you haven't overridden equals and hashcode. You also are going to find it very difficult to generate usable JSON from them. See: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization()

Comment: @Brian, would it be possible if I just used Map<String, List<ModuleParam>> instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Brian's comment I realized I had no need to use complex objects as keys so this was my solution.

```
public class ModuleParsed {

    String id_component;
    String id_instance;
    Map<String, ModuleParam> input;
    Map<String, List<ModuleParam>> output;
    int id_paas;
}

public class ModuleParam {

    String name;
    String id_module;
    String id_instance;
}
```

for which I built the following JSON

```
[
    {
        "id_component": "mod1",
        "id_instance": "mod1_inst1",
        "input": {
            "input1": {}
        },
        "output": {
            "output1": [
                {
                    "name": "input1",
                    "id_module": "mod2",
                    "id_instance": "mod2_inst1",
                    "type": "paramType"
                },
                {
                    "name": "input2",
                    "id_module": "mod2",
                    "id_instance": "mod2_inst1",
                    "type": "paramType"
                }
            ],
            "output2": []
        },
        "id_paas": 1
    },
    {
        "id_component": "mod2",
        "id_instance": "mod2_inst1",
        "input": {
            "input1": {
                "name": "output1",
                "id_module": "mod1",
                "id_instance": "mod1_inst1",
                "type": "paramType"
            },
            "input2": {
                "name": "output1",
                "id_module": "mod1",
                "id_instance": "mod1_inst1",
                "type": "paramType"
            }
        },
        "output": {},
        "id_paas": 1
    }
]
```

The JSON was parsed correctly this time.